# Collecting friends' wall posts

Tags: ruby, pagination

Originally, I had everything in the base method #read_wall(). I'm not sure what happened with the array, but when I tried:

`array = result + second + third + fourth`. I was left with data from only the original result. So I created this working disaster. **Can you please help me refactor this?**

```
   # Gets the user's Wall
      def read_wall(fbuserid)
         result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
      end

  def second_wall(fbuserid)
     result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
     second ||= result.next_page
  end

  def third_wall(fbuserid)
       result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
       second ||= result.next_page
       third ||= second.next_page
  end

  def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
        result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
        second ||= result.next_page
        third ||= second.next_page
        fourth ||= third.next_page
   end

  # Collects your friends' wall Posts and puts the IDs into an array
  def get_post_ids(fbuserid)
     x ||= read_wall(fbuserid)
     var = []
     for i in 0..25
        if find_nil(x, [i,'id']).nil? == false
           var << x[i]['id']
        end
     end

     second_wall ||= second_wall(fbuserid)
       for i in 0..25
          if find_nil(second_wall, [i,'id']).nil? == false
             var << second_wall[i]['id']
          end
       end

      third_wall ||= third_wall(fbuserid)
        for i in 0..25
           if find_nil(third_wall, [i,'id']).nil? == false
              var << third_wall[i]['id']
           end
        end

      fourth_wall ||= fourth_wall(fbuserid)
         for i in 0..25
            if find_nil(fourth_wall, [i,'id']).nil? == false
                 var << fourth_wall[i]['id']
            end
         end

      @get_post_ids = var
  end
```

Comment: Is it meaningful in Ruby to declare a local variable with the same name as a function and still expect to reference both in the same context? `second_wall ||= second_wall(fbuserid) ... find_nil(second_wall, ...)`

Comment: @David: Yes, `x = x()` works in ruby and sets the local variable `x` to the result of calling the method `x`. However it's not necessarily good style.

Comment: It should be obvious, but shadowing a method with a local variable is a terrible code smell, almost certain to cause confusion and trivial to avoid. So **don't do it**. There's no excuse.

Answer (score 13):

```
def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
  result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
  second ||= result.next_page
  third ||= second.next_page
  fourth ||= third.next_page
end
```

A couple of problems here: `result`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` are all local variables. This means they won't persist after the method call is finished and they will never persist after the method call is finished. So:

1. You don't need to set the `fourth` variable as you never use it in the method and it won't be available after
2. You don't need `||=` as the variables will never be set anyway.

I.e. your code is equivalent to this:

```
def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
  result = graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
  second = result.next_page
  third = second.next_page
  third.next_page
end
```

Or just:

```
def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
  graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed').next_page.next_page.next_page
end
```

The same goes for the other `wall` methods.

---

Further your `fourth_wall` method contains the entire code of the `third_wall` method (which contains the entire `second_wall` method and so on). This is bad style. Just let the methods call each other:

```
def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
  third_wall(fbuserid).next_page
end
```

(And again the same for the other `wall` methods of course)

---

However since you seem to only call those functions together (i.e. you never use `fourth_wall` without having used `third_wall` before) it seems much more sensible to have one method which returns all for walls:

```
def four_walls(fbuserid)
  first = graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
  # For more than 4 pages the following should be replaced by a loop
  second = first.next_page
  third = second.next_page
  fourth = third.next_page
  [first, second, third, fourth]
end
```

---

In your `get_post_ids` method you're repeating the same code four times. This is again bad style. You're also creating an empty array and then appending to it from a loop. This is often (but not always) a sign of bad code in ruby as well. Also using `x` and `var` as variable names is not a good idea and having a variable name that starts with `@get_` just seems weird and confusing.

I'm also assuming that your `find_nil` method is supposed to check whether either `wall[i]` or `wall[i]['id']` are nil. There are better ways to do this.

In this case you can use map on the walls and then the numbers from 0 to 25 to create an array of user ids for each wall, then use `compact` to remove `nil`s and `flatten` to turn the array into one single array rather than an array of four subarray. Thus your whole `get_post_ids` method can be replaced with this:

```
def retrieve_post_ids(fbuserid)
  walls = four_walls(fbuserid)
  @post_ids = walls.map do |wall|
    # Iterate over the first 26 entries in wall
    (0..25).map do |i|
      wall[i] && wall[i]['id']
     end.compact
  end.flatten
end
```

---

Though if the `wall`s allow slicing similar to arrays, this would be better:

```
def retrieve_post_ids(fbuserid)
  walls = four_walls(fbuserid)
  @post_ids = walls.map do |wall|
    # Iterate over the first 26 entries in wall
    wall[0..25].map do |entry|
      entry && entry['id']
     end.compact
  end.flatten
end
```

If the wall never contains more than 26 elements, you don't even need the `[0..25]` and you can just use `well.map`.

---

However it occurs to me that the reason you needed the nil check at all was that each wall contains 25 elements and you got `nil` for index `25` because you did not realize that ranges using `..` are inclusive. In that case you can just use:

```
def retrieve_post_ids(fbuserid)
  walls = four_walls(fbuserid)
  @post_ids = walls.map do |wall|
    # Iterate over the entries in wall
    wall.map do |entry|
      entry['id']
     end
  end.flatten
end
```

Comment: Everything I thought of with more besides!

Comment: Maybe use `flat_map` instead of 1st `map`, so we'll not need `flatten`.